# Beamer Headline

Tags: beamer

I am putting together a presentation for my Master's thesis defense with Beamer. I've tried to keep the number of sections small to consistently conserve space in the headline. However, in certain sections the number of subsections is greater and gets cutoff in the headline.

Is there any way I can dynamically increase/decrease the height of the headline based on the number of subsections in the current section? By default it seems to be exclusively determined by the number of sections.

I am using the beamerthemesplit package for theming.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please add to your question a [minimal working example](http://www.minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html) illustrating the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Can't reproduce this problem with Beamer 3.10, at least. Two representative empty frames shown below:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}

\begin{document}

\section{Section One}
\subsection{Subsection One} \frame{}
\subsection{Subsection Two} \frame{}
\subsection{Subsection Three} \frame{}

\section{Section Two}
\subsection{Subsection One} \frame{}
\subsection{Subsection Two} \frame{}
\subsection{Subsection Three} \frame{}

\section{Section Three}
\subsection{Subsection One} \frame{}
\subsection{Subsection Two} \frame{}
\subsection{Subsection Three} \frame{}

\section{Section Four}
\subsection{Subsection One} \frame{}
\subsection{Subsection Two} \frame{}
\subsection{Subsection Three} \frame{}
\subsection{Subsection Four} \frame{}
\subsection{Subsection Five} \frame{}
\subsection{Subsection Six} \frame{}
\subsection{Subsection Seven} \frame{}

\end{document}
```